# Do chess clocks typically provide count up features?

Tags: chess-clocks, equipment

I've decided to purchase a chess clock for productivity at work, and I really like the dual display of the chess clock: one timer for work, another timer for fooling around. However, I'd like to know, do game clocks typically offer count-up mode rather than count down?

Answer (score 5):

It is not a typical use case, so you will definitely want to make sure that the clock you're purchasing does have a count-up mode (or is analog, in which case, you probably want to make sure it is quiet). The Chronos digital clock does have a couple of count-up modes (UP-1 and UP-2).

Answer (score 3):

I've never heard of any digital ones that do, but the old analog clocks count up, of course.

Interesting idea.

Answer (score 2):

Here is an online version of what I think you are looking for:

[chess timer](http://www.online-stopwatch.com/chess-timer/)

Answer (score 1):

The Leap [PQ9907S](https://chessdelights.com/setup-leap-pq9907s-chess-clock/) has count up as the default mode!